# Making the right side of divs line up instead of the left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 divs, one on top of another. You see how the left side of the red bordered div is lined up with the left side of the blue bordered div? My question is, is there a way to make the right side of the red bordered div line up with the right side of the blue bordered div?

```css
#top {
   border: 1px solid red;
   display: inline-block;
}

#bottom {
   border: 1px solid blue;
   width: 25%;
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'top'> top </div>
<div id = 'bottom'> bottom </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have a container and float the elements inside to the right:

```css
#top {
   border: 1px solid red;
   display: inline-block;
   float: right;
}

#bottom {
   border: 1px solid blue;
   width: 25%;
   display: block;
   clear:both;
   float: right;
}

#container {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id = 'top'> top </div>
    <div id = 'bottom'> bottom </div>
</div>
```